# Java main: args.length incorrect?

Tags: java

I print `args.length`, it says 5.

I also print the arguments via `for(int i = 0; i < args.length;i++)` and i see 4 arguments.

What's wrong here?

Heres the code:

```
System.out.println(args.length);
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
            System.out.println(args[i]);
        }
```

and my arguments are:
~/Desktop/Master_Bioinformatik/Data_Mining_in Bioinformatics/Project/stockori/joint.csv 2 3.2 euclidean

EDIT: okay i oversaw something, actually the output is:

5Exception in thread "main" 
~/Desktop/Master_Bioinformatik/Data_Mining_in
Bioinformatics/Project/stockori/joint.csv
2
3.2
euclidean

that exception phrase is written in red. i thought it was some graphics error. but it reappears. why is that?

Comment: what args are you passing?

Comment: Try printing args too

Comment: these ones:~/Desktop/Master_Bioinformatik/Data_Mining_in Bioinformatics/Project/stockori/joint.csv 2 3.2 euclidean

Comment: You could be passing an empty argument. Like Batty said, showing us what args you are passing would be helpful.

Comment: What is more likely:  That the JDK, which has been running on millions, if not billions, of machines for probably 20 years has a bug in it, or your code has a bug in it?

Comment: Using a debugger would tell you what the args array contains. Please do such elementary problem analysis before posting on stackoverflow.

Comment: lol codechimp :) considering my enormous level of skill, I assume the former :P complete code added above

Comment: @user3182532 I have been developing professionally in Java since 1998...I ALWAYS assume it's my code first.  Saves a lot of time that way.

Comment: what's the output of `which java`?

Answer (score 3):

5 arguments (you have a space in that dir name):

~/Desktop/Master_Bioinformatik/Data_Mining_in

Bioinformatics/Project/stockori/joint.csv

2

3.2

euclidean

Comment: no there is no space! i know now why there's 5 arguments. args[0] = "exception in thread main". but i have no idea why i have this argument

Comment: i have edited the output in the first post. sorry for the missing newlines, i do not understand why stackoverflow doesn't post them :/

Comment: okay actually that red written exception phrase WAS a graphics error. but still there is no space!

Comment: The exception shouldn't count as part of your args if it's not part of your input. However, I still see a space before "Bioinformatics". To print newlines on stackoverflow, try two newlines each time (that's what I did above)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe one of you arguments is an empty string ("").

If your are using System.out.println() you could look at how many lines are printed.

**Edit :**

If you see the right number of lines printed it's possible you are modifying args without realizing it. Have you tried making it `final`?

Stepping through your code with a watch on argc could also be useful.

Comment: then i should see an empty newline when printing the arguments, but there is none :/

Comment: "" this is not new line

Comment: @Batty If you print `System.out.println(args[i]);`, and empty argument will be seen as empty line.

Comment: yes right rohit -> i have added the code in the first post